# How to search abbreviation word "ITS" for "Information Technology Service" in Solr

Tags: search, solr, schema

In my dataset, the word "ITS" means "Information Technology Service". However, when I search "ITS" in solr, I get results like "it", "it's" and "its" (adjective). No results are related to "Information Technology Service". How can I change Solr for this purpose?

My schema for the filed is listed below. I actually use two field. One with stemming and the other without stemming. But it still does not work.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"
            positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"
                    splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"
                    protected="protwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>

    <!-- for no stemming -->
<fieldType name="text_no_stemming" class="solr.TextField"
    positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>                
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not letting Solr know ITS is a synonym for "Information Technology Service". You need to do that first, check [SynonymFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#SynonymFilter)

Comment: I am not sure if SynonymFilter works. For example, suppose I write a simple rule, such as it, its, it's => Information Technology Service. If a document just contains sentence like "It is rainy.". Will this sentence be indexed as "Information Technology Service is rainy"?

Comment: if you mean 'its' can sometime mean Information Technology Service and sometimes can also mean 'its' then sorl cannot differentiate among those by itself. You could preprocess the input with some NLP and try to disambiguate

Comment: Do you know any NLP library easy to integrate into Solr?

Comment: set ignoreCase="false" so ITS is seen different than its